# SQL procedure using OUTPUT clause doesn't return value

Tags: c#, sql, procedure

I have built a procedure which should insert a new row into a table and return its id.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertFood]
AS 
 DECLARE @ID TABLE (foodId INT)
 insert into TblFood
 OUTPUT INSERTED.foodId INTO @ID(foodId) 
 default values 
 select * from @ID
 return
```

When I run this procedure it always returns 0.

Comment: Are you sure that all columns accept default values or are nullable?  Show the `create table` statement for `tblFood`.  Is the default value for the columns `0`?

Comment: for every column besides the foodId which is auto identity. it looks like this ((0)) NOT NULL for every colomn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REad this MSDN post provide example : [Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory
  @CategoryName nvarchar(15),
  @Identity int OUT
AS
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertFood]
AS 
 DECLARE @ID int 
 --insert data in table Example 
  ----INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)
  ----VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE()); 
 --insert data in table 
 select @ID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 return @ID
```

You can use [Scope_Identity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to get the last value.

Comment: What @@Identity means?

Comment: @Nityuiop18 = you can check here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx

Comment: It doesn't work when I am trying to update the procedure

Comment: @Nityuiop18 - check my example you can try like that

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of `@@IDENTITY` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @Nityuiop18 . . . The `output` clause is the safest way to get the identity.  If it doesn't work, the other methods should similarly fail.

Comment: And of course, your answer also assumes that the OP says `SQL` and really means **`SQL Server`** by that - right?